# Converting Aspx page from VB to CS

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp.net page WineCompDefault.aspx which was initially implemented with VB code behind. I am now trying to change the code behind to CS. I modified the page directive in the aspx page as follows:

From -

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="WineCompDefault.aspx.vb" Inherits="WineCompDefault" %>
```

To -

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="WineCompDefault.aspx.cs" Inherits="WineCompDefaultCS" %>
```

The WineCompDefault.aspx.vb file contained the following:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports MarymonteDAL
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb


Partial Class WineCompDefault
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnLogOn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogOn.Click
        Dim myLabel As Label
        myLabel = Page.FindControl("lblTitle")
        If Not myLabel Is Nothing Then
            lblResults.Text = myLabel.Text
        Else
            lblResults.Text = "Could not find the label control."
        End If
        btnLogOn.Visible = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

And the code converter from VB to C# gave the following (except I changed the class name to WineCompDefaultCS which I also changed in the page directive, so I could have both code behind files in the project)

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;


partial class WineCompDefaultCS : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btnLogOn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Label myLabel = default(Label);
        myLabel = Page.FindControl("lblTitle");
        if ((myLabel != null)) {
            lblResults.Text = myLabel.Text;
        } else {
            lblResults.Text = "Could not find the label control.";
        }
        btnLogOn.Visible = false;
    }

    Public WineCompDefault()
    {
        Load += Page_Load;
    }
}
```

The problem is it says "The type or namespace Public could not be found". I do not know what is wrong or missing. All help greatly appreciated.

(Also, note, I will remove the VB file once I am sure the CS is working correctly. That is why I would like to keep both in the project at this time)

Comment: Your class name is WineCompDefaultCS, but your constructors name is WineCompDefault.

Comment: and access modifiers are case sensitive - public not Public

Comment: That seems to be the solution...case sensitive and renaming the constructor. Thanks to all!!

Comment: One last question (I hope!). I have a VB module and I need to call subs and functions in that module from the CS code. I do not know how to reference those functions. I tries a using statement with the module name but that was incorrect. How should I be doing this? For example the module name is WineCompBLL.vb and I need to access the function GetUser that returns a string. Again, thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

You renamed the class but not the constructor. In C#, the constructor must match the class name.

WineCompDefault should be WineCompDefaultCS

Comment: I should also note I am running this within VS2005 and so I have both CS and VB code files. Is that allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is incorrect. The constructor must always match the class name (`WineCompDefaultCS`). In addition, c# is case sensitive and access modifiers such as `public` should be lower case.

**Change this:**

```
Public WineCompDefault()
{
    Load += Page_Load;
}
```

**To this:**

```
public WineCompDefaultCS()
{
    Load += Page_Load;
}
```

Comment: When I do that it says - 'WineCompDefaultCS': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Answer (score 0):

An old question - but this is what I could find till now -

You need to delete the file and add it back using Add->New File (this time select the c#) and then paste back the aspx (with lang="C#" and CodeFile="WineCompDefault.aspx.cs")

I don't know why or how Visual Studio knows about the way the page was initially converted - I couldn't find out where VS stores this information.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

you are missing a return statement

Comment: Please be more specific with your answers.